# Inserting Vertical Space Before Index Heading Items with Filecontents

Tags: indexing, makeindex, vertical-spacing, filecontents, idxlayout

I recently discovered a seemingly simple way to insert vertical space immediately before new index headings using `filecontents`---

Consider the code

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.mst}
item_0 "\n\\vspace{15pt}\\item "
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\makeindex
\usepackage[initsep=25pt]{idxlayout} % initsep declares spacing between letter groups.


\begin{document}
\LARGE
Some words.\index{HEADING1! Subheading! Index entry1.}

Some words.\index{HEADING2! Subheading! Index entry2.}

Some more words.\index{NEXT SET OF HEADINGS1! Subheading! Index entry1.}

Some more words.\index{NEXT SET OF HEADINGS2! Subheading! Index entry2.}
\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

which yields

[image]

The only concern I have is that this approach adds the prescribed vertical space to *all* heading groups; and thus, to the first heading group under each new alphabet letter (in this example, *H* and *N*)---thus increasing the gap between **Index** and the *H* grouping, as well as between the *H* grouping and the *N* grouping.

Observe, that without the use of `filecontents` in the code, the Index output would look like this:

[image]

I would like to have the additional vertical space (in this case, `\vspace{15pt}`) inserted before all the indicated items *except* those that represent the first under a given alphabetic letter.

QUESTION: Without resorting to a horrible "hack" (is that appropriate terminology here?) such as `\index{\vspace{-15pt}HEADING1! Subheading! Index entry1.}` and `\index{\vspace{-15pt}NEXT SET OF HEADINGS1! Subheading! Index entry1.}`---which incidentally, could require up to 26 such insertions---I would like to know if there is an efficient way to accomplish this?

*Remark*: I am reluctant to abandon the `filecontents` approach, for without it, it seems to me that  procedures for adding vertical space to the aforementioned items is quite complicated (unlike inserting vertical space at other places; e.g., immediately *after* each new heading.)

Thank you.

Comment: don't you just want `initsep=10pt`subtracting the15pt you have added everywhere?

Comment: @David Carlisle Ah! Thank you for that clever solution.